# Get ContentEditable Selection

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I need to add a classname to the selected text of a ContentEditable textarea. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6kxh2s4/).
The problem I am facing is that the function window.getSelection() only returns the content until the first HTML tag.

For example, if the content in the textarea is:

```
<p>
testing1
</p><p>
testing2</p>
```

The function would return only testing1 or testing2, despite the fact that I highlighted all the content.

The javascript code to capture the content is:

```
document.querySelector("#ce").addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
  userSelection= window.getSelection().toString();
});
```

How can I write a javascript function that returns all the selected text or node?

Thanks

Comment: That works for me in the Fiddle

Comment: @EzequielFernandez if you select all the content and click on Get Selection you won't get either, I need to get the two <p>

Comment: are you sure? I can select the whole text and even add more text and select it. Then the Get Selection show everything selected...